# how throw exception when user store string in float variable?

Tags: c++, exception

```
float input;
cin>>input; // if the user type string in input then throw exception
if(!isdigit(input)){
     throw "error";
}
```

But isdigit also throw exception for a numeric value.

How to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
float input;
if (cin>>input) {
  //all is good
  ...
} else {
     throw "error";
}
```

is one way to go. Program will take `if` path if the input begins with a number and `else` path otherwise.

Comment: this always throw exception even if i type a numeric value.

Comment: sorry there was an error in my code. it worked. Thanks